# adding rows to a datatable #2

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a data table, and some columns are strings, some are decimal. When I add a row, will it automatically convert the info or do I have to convert them myself? I have a lot of data that I need to add in a table and currently I am using this:

```
DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
row["item1"] = Info[0];
row["Item2"] = Info[1];
row["item3"] = Info[2];
row["Item4"] = Convert.ToDecimal(Info[3]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

row["..."] is a object and will take any type. If your Info[n] is a string you can convert it to the right type if need be. I don't know if Info is a collection or not but if it is, why not do something like this instead:

```
List<Info> infoList = new List<Info>();
infoList.Add(...); //Add item here.

foreach(Info info in infoList)
{
   DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow(); 
   row["item1"] = info.Item1; //where Item1 could be a string 
   row["Item2"] = info.Item2; //where Item2 could be an int
   row["item3"] = info.Item3; //Where Item3 could be a DateTime
   row["Item4"] = info.Item4; //Where Item4 could be a Decimal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alex Mendez please take a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx, I think that you are missing the indicated line of code (see below):

```
foreach(Info info in infoList)
{
   DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow(); 
   row["item1"] = info.Item1; //where Item1 could be a string 
   row["Item2"] = info.Item2; //where Item2 could be an int
   row["item3"] = info.Item3; //Where Item3 could be a DateTime
   row["Item4"] = info.Item4; //Where Item4 could be a Decimal
   dataTable.Rows.Add(row); //<-- You need to add this line to actually save the value to the Data Table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the documentation: [Datatable Addrow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If your DataTable is not typed, yes you have to convert data to the intended types, in case of typed DataTable it converts the data, like:

```
int number = "0";
```

You can also set the column types.